# BuildConfig not getting created correctly (Gradle Android)

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-gradle-plugin, buildconfig

I am trying to convert our Android application to a gradle build.  I have the project and it's libraries building successfully.   I am now trying to create separate apks for our various environments (dev/test/prod have different urls for the restful services they consume).

In searching around, the best way that I feel to do this is with making different BuildConfig for each environment.   This is what I tried:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

task('increaseVersionCode') << {
    def manifestFile = file("AndroidManifest.xml")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def versionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode=\"" + ++versionCode + "\"")
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildConfig') {
        task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0' 
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar',
                  'libs/google-play-services.jar',
                  'libs/gson-2.2.4.jar',
                  'libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.6.jar',
                  'libs/wakeful-1.0.1.jar')
    compile project(':pulltorefresh_lib')
    compile project(':edgeeffect_lib')
    compile project(':viewpagerindicator_lib')        
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18"

    defaultConfig { 
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
        dev.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        dev {
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEARCH", "\"https://dev-search.example.com\";"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_CONNECT", "\"https://dev-connect.example.com\";"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_SVC_NEWSLIST", "\"https://dev-mobilenews.example.com/newslist\";"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_SVC_NEWSDETAIL", "\"https://dev-mobilenews.example.com/newsdetail\";"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_SVC_REGISTERENDPOINTS", "\"https://dev-mobilenews.example.com/registerendpoints\";"
        }
        prod.initWith(buildTypes.release)
        prod {
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEARCH", "\"https://search.example.com\";"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_CONNECT", "\"https://connect.example.com\";"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_SVC_NEWSLIST", "\"https://mobilenews.example.com/newslist\";"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_SVC_NEWSDETAIL", "\"https://mobilenews.example.com/newsdetail\";"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_SVC_REGISTERENDPOINTS", "\"https://mobilenews.pdc-np-cf.lmig.com/registerendpoints\";"          
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my BuildConfig.java doesn't seem to get the static variables injected, therefore I get errors similar to:

```
/Users/path/to/project/MainActivity.java:348: error: cannot find symbol
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(BuildConfig.URL_SEARCH)));
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable URL_SEARCH
  location: class BuildConfig
/Users/path/to/project/MainActivity.java:359: error: cannot find symbol
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(BuildConfig.URL_CONNECT)));
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable URL_CONNECT
  location: class BuildConfig
/Users/path/to/project/MainActivity.java:600: error: cannot find symbol
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BuildConfig.URL_SVC_REGISTERENDPOINTS);
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable URL_SVC_REGISTERENDPOINTS
  location: class BuildConfig
/Users/path/to/project/service/AlarmNotificationService.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
        String requestUrl = BuildConfig.URL_SVC_NEWSLIST + "?"
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable URL_SVC_NEWSLIST
  location: class BuildConfig
/Users/path/to/project/service/NewsService.java:240: error: cannot find symbol
        String requestUrl = BuildConfig.URL_SVC_NEWSLIST + "?"
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable URL_SVC_NEWSLIST
  location: class BuildConfig
/Users/path/to/project/service/NewsService.java:530: error: cannot find symbol
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BuildConfig.URL_SVC_NEWSDETAIL);
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable URL_SVC_NEWSDETAIL
  location: class BuildConfig
6 errors
```

My build/source/buildConfig/debug/com/.../BuildConfig.java file contains:

```
/**
 * Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
 */
package com....;

public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.....debug";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 5;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might make sense to remove those Liberty references. Not that there's any critical code here, but it's best to avoid sharing proprietary code on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: see below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604627/gradle-buildconfigfield-buildconfig-cannot-resolve-symbol

Comment: Check answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604627/gradle-buildconfigfield-buildconfig-cannot-resolve-symbol

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Please, be sure that you are building "dev" or "prod" variant. There is no BuildConfig definition in default "debug" and "release" variant. In Android Studio, you can select current variant in bottom left corner:

[image: Build Variants]

To simplify your build.gradle file, you can define:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEARCH", "\"https://dev-search.example.com\""
        // etc.
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEARCH", "\"https://search.example.com\""
        // etc.      
    }
}
```

and then just use default "debug" and "release" variants.

At last, delete semicolon (sign: ';') from the value of buildConfigField parameter.

Comment: Thanks...it was me being daft, as I expected.   "gradle installDev" works fine...."gradle build" was giving me errors.

Comment: you can also go like this `buildConfigField 'String', 'URL_SEARCH', '"https://search.example.com"'`

Comment: I want to add that you might require to rebuild the project (`Build` -> `Rebuild Project`) when changing the active build variant else the `BuildConfig` will not be regenerated.

Answer (score 140):

In my case I had to enable buildConfig as a build feature.

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }
}
```

Comment: and after that do this : 
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: You need to clean the project and rebuild it after doing this

Comment: It worked for me. But why do we need to add buildConfig true. I did not get this.

Comment: The only one solution works for me (saved my day)

Comment: This happened to be a solution for me on Android Studio Giraffe. Thank you

Comment: The only right answer, tks

Comment: Right answer for me, thanks!

Comment: Okey, this is for me working.

Comment: Thank you. 9 years after your answer, you are more more right than ever, because AGP 8.0 changed the default value of buildConfig from true to false.
https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes#default-changes

Comment: I want to also mention that you need to put this in each of your modules' ```build.gradle``` files if you have more than one, because the ```gradle.properties``` entry was applying to all modules but this won't.

Comment: This should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 63):

first do

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart
```

then do

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

then do

```
Build - > Rebuild Project
```

Comment: After doing this Gradle finally reported that the minimum SDK of one of the libraries used is higher than the apps minsdk

Comment: confirm, it worked

Comment: Hurray ! It works!
Thank you @Mirza Ahmed

Answer (score 58):

I had same issue and fixed it like below:

```
buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"https://api.example.com"'
```

Comment: for `String`, double-quotation does NOT generate properly. only single-quotation generates variable successfully.

Comment: For those like me who missed it the first time, the key part is that the value is in double-quotes inside of the single-quotes.

Answer (score 23):

Just in case that helps somebody else, in my case it was a missing import:
`import uk.co.yourpackage.yourapp.BuildConfig;`

Somehow, nowhere in the doc does it mention you need that include! Made me think it was automatically imported somehow but it ISN'T. not for me at least... So much time lost... Hope that helps another newbie like me!

Comment: Amazing , it was import problem, I was import from android.support.v4.BuildConfig 
Thank you :)

Comment: I had "org.koin.android" imported by accident and it has its own BuildConfig for some reason. Thank you for this comment, it reminded me to manually check the import!

Comment: I have tried virtually everything to no luck

Answer (score 14):

Add this in `build.gradle`

```
buildFeatures {
    buildConfig = true
}
```

if using jet pack compose

```
 buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

Try to do

> Build -> Clean Project

then do

> Build - > Rebuild Project

If it doesn't work, try

> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

then do

> Build -> Clean Project

then do

> Build - > Rebuild Project

Comment: Clean and rebuild should work - worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

You need to have this line in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

I solve this problem as given below
in this case Android studio will generate Build Config file itself

```
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

Comment: This one helped me

Comment: work for me . thanks!! (android studio 2020.03.01 patch.3  )

Answer (score 6):

Very logical Answer if this is not heppening in compose

```
    buildFeatures {
    // The first line should already be in your project!
    compose = true
    buildConfig = true
    }
```

This will now generate the file and you can use the BuildConfig.Debug in Application and everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

**For Android Studio Version**

> Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
>
> Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
>
> Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 aarch64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit
> Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

**What was I trying to do?**

I set up three build variants for the app module, I wanted BuildConfig to be changed every time I change the build variant, for that particular variable defined in the build.gradle (app) configurations.

**What didn't work**

I have tried all three methods, **DIDN'T WORK AT ALL**, to regenerate my BuildConfig for the build variant I was changing:

1. `File > invalidate cache and restart` along with `Build > Clean Project` & `Build > Rebuild Project`
2. `Build > Make Project` alone
3. `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files` alone

**What worked**

Then I tried a combination which is surprisingly **WORKING WELL**:

1. First, Try `Build > Make Project`
2. Then `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files`

I hope it will work for that particular version I am not sure for other versions of Android Studio.

Thanks, @ravi, and @ibrokhim for partially answered for the case.

Comment: This one worked for Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 too on Macbook air M2. Confirmed!

Comment: @smnadim21 Happy to know the solution is still working for the latest updates of Android Studio, cheers man. And I would suggest you to edit the answer in a appropriate manner so that it may helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what fixed this for me:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are modifying your Environment Variables, and they are not reflecting correctly in Android studio try doing:

```
Build -> Clean Project 
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I did all the things in the answers but still didn't work. I solved my problem by changing the package name in the `manifest.xml` file which still hadn't been updated :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.android">
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

**Step 1**

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart
```

**Step 2**

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

**Step 3**

```
Build - > Rebuild Project
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything, switching the build variant and selecting **Build > Make Project**  worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the project.ext.envConfigFiles array, ensure you set the debug to the right .env file you are using for development

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem related to build types being setup using `.initWith(someotherbuildtype)`, `BuildConfig` was not being created properly. I had to switch to the parent build variant and build that first, then the build types that initWith the parent built fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was expecting the BuildConfig for my new gradle module created. But forgot to add it as a dependency in app: module.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an string field `resValue "string", "app_name", "MyApp"` in strings.xml as well as in product flavours.

I did `Invalidate Caches` then `Rebuild` then android studion given the actual error of duplicate resources.

so `Invalidate caches -> Rebuild -> Remove string resources which were already in buildconfigfield resvalue` worked for me

I was using `Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me, I closed the project and opened again, and then rebuilt it because it clears all the generated stuff on closing and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**In My Case I have First**

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart
```

**When project Restarts  than**

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

**After Cleaning**`

```
    Build -> Rebuild Project
```