# BuildConfig variable. Error: cannot find symbol

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In project I have several `flavors`, several `buildTypes` and several `folders` for combinations

Build combinations:

[image]

Folder structure

[image]

In each folder I have custom `Application class` + `AndroidManifest` to register this `Application class`

[image]

Sometime, but just **sometimes** build fails with `cannot find symbol` error:

```
\app\src\main\java\ru\my\package\app\environment\MyApp.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!BuildConfig.ANALYTICS).build())
```

or `App` class independent but the same error

```
\app\src\main\java\ru\my\package\presentation\presenter\impl\MainPresenterImpl.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
    if (!BuildConfig.ANALYTICS) return;
```

But the very next build could be successful, so the possible flow is

1. Build (successful)
2. Some chagnes in the code
3. Build (error)
4. Build-retry (successful) <-- without any changes in code

**Note**

- It's not a **sync** problem and sync/invalidate cache is not the answer
- It's not a wrong `import` problem

Disclaimer: there are questions that looks like this one, but they're different, e.g.

[Gradle buildConfigField BuildConfig cannot resolve symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604627/gradle-buildconfigfield-buildconfig-cannot-resolve-symbol)

**UPDATE**

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(path: ':OVSALibrary')
    implementation project(path: ':YaMapProject')
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'eu.davidea:flexible-adapter:5.0.0-rc3'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_lib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_lib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_lib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_lib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji:$support_lib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji-appcompat:$support_lib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji-bundled:$support_lib_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
    implementation 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
    implementation 'nl.big-o:liqp:0.7.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation ('com.github.revern:socket.io-client-java:master-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.luckycatlabs:SunriseSunsetCalculator:1.2'
    implementation ('com.github.developer-shivam:Crescento:1.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'palette-v7'
    }
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.malinskiy:superrecyclerview:1.1.4'

    // Yandex.Map things
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'

    // Yandex ads. Adfox.
    rcImplementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:3.0.0'
    debugWithAnalyticsImplementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:3.0.0'
    releaseImplementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:2.71'


    // Waiting for https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView/pull/287
    // Waiting for https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView/pull/288
    implementation 'com.github.dryaz:CompactCalendarView:master-SNAPSHOT'

    // Waiting for https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar/pull/57
    implementation 'com.github.dryaz:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:master-SNAPSHOT'

    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // PAY SDK
    implementation(name:'mos-pay-sdk-1.0.9', ext:'aar')
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
    implementation ('eu.livotov.labs.android:3DSView:1.1.2@aar') {transitive=true}

    // Android Architecture Components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$androidArch"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$androidArch"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$androidArch"

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
}
```

** UPDATE **
Here's the list of `buildTypes` and `productFlavors`

```
flavorDimensions("devbeta", "mainmirror")
    productFlavors {
        // Beta API enviroment
        beta {
            dimension = "devbeta"
            buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_REMOTE_PATH", "\"/api-beta/socket.io\""
        }

        // Dev API enviroment
        dev {
            dimension = "devbeta"
            buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_REMOTE_PATH", "\"/api-dev/socket.io\""
        }

        // Prod API enviroment
        prod {
            dimension = "devbeta"
            buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_REMOTE_PATH", "\"/socket.io\""
        }

        mainhost {
            dimension = "mainmirror"
            buildConfigField "String", "CONFIG_REMOTE_HOSTNAME", "\"some.host.url\""
        }

        mirrorhost {
            dimension = "mainmirror"
            buildConfigField "String", "CONFIG_REMOTE_HOSTNAME", "\"some.host.url\""
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ANALYTICS", "false"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.customDebug
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    firebaseAnalyticsDeactivated: "true",
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_debug",
            ]
        }

        debugWithAnalytics.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        debugWithAnalytics {
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "group-internal"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = "$getReleaseNotes"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ANALYTICS", "true"
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }

        debugWithProguard.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        debugWithProguard {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles(file('./proguard').listFiles())
            matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
        }

        // RC build for inner testers that has analytics, signed with debug key.
        rc {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles(file('./proguard').listFiles())
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ANALYTICS", "true"
            // Fields for fabric beta distribution
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "group-internal"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = "$getReleaseNotes"

            signingConfig signingConfigs.customDebug

            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    firebaseAnalyticsDeactivated: "false",
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_rc",
            ]
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }

        release.initWith(buildTypes.rc)
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ANALYTICS", "true"
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "group-customer"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    firebaseAnalyticsDeactivated: "false",
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: why u added tools:replace="android:name"

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki because I need to use different App classes in different flavors, it's used in order to replace App implementation with flavor's one.

Comment: can u please add gradle dependency

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki updated my pos

Comment: @dilix build fails when you switch variant or building same variant after code changes ?

Comment: @Qasim buildind the same variant after code changes fails

Comment: The class icon on the structure screenshot shows an error, can you show the class definition. Is it possible to put these different app classes in different source routes? (can you use a single app class with composition based on flavours, to simplify things?)

Comment: @NickCardoso it showsh the error because current selected build variant is not Rc, it's ok. I can't use one APP class, because I have some dependencies that shouldn't be added in default config but are needed in other configs and they're used in 'APP' class, so I need to have an APP class for each flavor where I have this dependency.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying - use composition for those parts. Then the dependency is on the composite component and the App functions like an interface to them

Comment: I can't even add dependency to the main part of the app because in this case lib will bring a service that lives in other thread and prevent instant run usage. So I use rcImplementation, releaseImplementation etc. but can't use just 'implementation' and in this case I can't import dependencies from the lib in any part of main code.

Comment: Have you try to disable "instant run"?

Comment: @ivan.panasiuk yes I do

Comment: Can you show buildTypes and productFlavors config from build.gradle?

Comment: @Link182 you could check it in updated question

Comment: i think its a problem of resources, you are using firebaseAnalyticsDeactivated in debug mode and their is version mismatch in firebase library  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0',
so my suggestion is : 
1) use same version of firebase library in overall project
2) delete build folder of all module 
3) And go to the File>Invalidate Caches/Restart>Invalidate and Restart

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally looks like I've found a reason, I have the library project exactly with the same package ID as the main `app`, so the inner `BuildConfig` for library project doesn't contain variable.

Comment: Another tip: I kept invalidating cache and cleaning project to see if I could import the right BuildConfig, but nothing worked. I even deleted .idea and .gradle folders to see if regenerating them would solve it, but still it wouldn't work. I also reimported the project, nothing. Then I decided to rebuild the project just for the sake of it and it worked.

Comment: So what do you do to solve it?

Comment: At the first place I could suggest to avoid having the same package IDs for lib and app itself.

Answer (score 5):

This helped me.

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
       buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

And rebuild project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Might be complete nonsense, but have you ever tested it with putting a default value directly in your defaultConfig?

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "boolean", "ANALYTICS", "false"
}
```

Comment: Nice idea but it doesn't help :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In my projects all custom values are mostly in my `productFlavors` instead of in the `buildTypes`, but that won't help either I assume.

Comment: This helped. Seems like I have to keep this custom buildConfigField. If I remove it, the build starts failing again. Even if I just reference available fields like ´BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME´.

Answer (score 2):

Rebuild Project if you have still problem on importing Package Name and then .BuildConfig

Answer (score 1):

I also have flavors in my app and I got to know that if I use **debugVariant** than `BuildConfig` creates and works well but if I try to use **releaseVariant** to work on than it can't create `BuildConfig` file.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar error, i.e. can't resolve `BuildConfig.FOO` , it's because of some other places has red mark error, e.g. you might unnoticed `AndroidManifest.xml` contains non-existent service class marked in red color. Fixed the service class first, then rebuild, the red color on `BuildConfig.FOO` are gone.

The lesson learned was don't focus at fixing specific red color which you don't see anything wrong, instead try look at other file and fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had another component which included an extra import that interfered with my base BuildConfig file

Look for imports from external libraries or components such as

```
import com.dpizarro.uipicker.library.BuildConfig;
```

and just delete them and rebuild.