# BuildConfig cannot create values correctly from variables (Gradle Android)

Tags: android, android-studio

## Goal

Building APKs for different environments using build types

## Approach

I'm using this [post](https://jrichardsz.github.io/android/how-to-build-an-android-apk-using-only-linux-for-devops-automations) to build my apk without android studio. Everything works except when I use environment variables in gradle:

Before build, I set the environment variable

```
export MY_API_TOKEN="ABCDEFGH"
```

Then in my build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {

  debug {
    buildConfigField("String", "MY_API_TOKEN", System.getenv('MY_API_TOKEN'))
  }

}
```

And when I execute : **gradle assemble** I get this error:

```
/home/apps/app/src/main/java/com/my/package/controller/api/MyAwesomeCode.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
                BuildConfig.MY_API_TOKEN;
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class RestAPI
/home/apps/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/my/package/BuildConfig.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
  public static final String MY_API_TOKEN = ABCDEFGH;
                                               ^
  symbol:   variable ABCDEFGH
  location: class BuildConfig
```

I tried with several combinations, and I get the same error:

- [BuildConfig not getting created correctly (Gradle Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706451/buildconfig-not-getting-created-correctly-gradle-android)
- [BuildConfig variable. Error: cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999485/buildconfig-variable-error-cannot-find-symbol/52147911)
- https://medium.com/@rafamatias/gradle-android-build-variables-done-right-d0c0e296ee93
- [Gradle : how to use BuildConfig in an android-library with a flag that gets set in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365928/gradle-how-to-use-buildconfig-in-an-android-library-with-a-flag-that-gets-set)

I also verified the same behavior with variables

```
def MY_API_TOKEN_VAR = "ABCDEFGH"

debug {
  buildConfigField "String", "MY_API_TOKEN", MY_API_TOKEN_VAR
}
```

Error :

```
BuildConfig.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
public static final String MY_API_TOKEN = ABCDEFGH;
                                          ^
symbol:   variable ABCDEFGH
location: class BuildConfig
```

## Question

**buildTypes** works only for hardcoded values in build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming given `export MY_API_TOKEN="ABC"` (please make sure variable is visible for your build system of choice) and your config is configured like this:

```
buildConfigField("String", "MY_API_TOKEN", "\"" + System.getenv("MY_API_TOKEN") + "\"")
```

...your BuildConfig class will have this extra field after sync/rebuild:

```
public static final String MY_API_TOKEN = "ABC";
```

Answer (score 0):

BuildConfig field values with string type should be declared with the field value in escaped quotes:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        def MY_API_TOKEN_VAR = "ABCDEFGH"
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_API_TOKEN", "\"ABCDEFGH\""
    }
    ...
}
```

With system environment variable:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        def MY_API_TOKEN_VAR = System.getenv('MY_API_TOKEN')
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_API_TOKEN", "\"ABCDEFGH\""
    }
    ...
}
```

When you don't declare the field value in escaped quotes, you can see the syntax error in generated `BuildConfig`:

```java
public final class BuildConfig {
  // ...
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final String MY_API_TOKEN = ABCD; // Should be "ABCD"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Natig. I tried but the error is the same. Please if you can, check my attempts: https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/803ebd6eec990f6880ff16b5e6b5b194   **attempt_2**  is the most promising

Comment: Second attempt is not promising, because as I mentioned in my explanation, you cannot set value for string without escaped quotes when creating buildConfigField. Check my updated code to fix the issue.

Comment: I mean promising because, at least value is replaced. With attempt_1 , the error is before replacement.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm not using android studio, just full linux shell with a minimal text editor. I appreciate your time and attention.