# BuildConfig cannot resolve solution

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart

**Gradle buildConfigField BuildConfig cannot resolve symbol**

In latest android studio with gradle version 8.0.0 and above developer face this issu. When they try to import BuildConfig class with own package name but it's can't working. From the import can not found own packagename. So, developer confused why it's not showing and take to much time for solving this issue.

But this is new feature provided by latest android studio with gradle version 8.0.0 and above. So, you just place simple code as showing below in **build.gradle** file.

```
android {
  buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
 }
```

**Why use buildFeatures?**

A list of build features that can be disabled or enabled in an Android Application project. A list of build features that can be disabled or enabled in an Android Dynamic Feature project.

**buildConfig**

```
abstract var buildConfig: Boolean?
```

Flag to enable/disable generation of the BuildConfig class.

Setting the value to null resets to the default value. Default value is true.

You can override the default for this for all projects in your build by adding the line **android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true** in the gradle.properties file at the root project of your build.

Comment: Thanks for this!  This is the first place I found a solution for the Gradle 8.0 issue.

Comment: What is your question here? This reads more like a blog post? You can answer your own question if you found a solution, but there needs to be at least a question, and then the answer should be posted as an answer, not as an edit to the question. Please check the [tour].