# Preprocesor for Android

Tags: java, android, preprocessor

Less than a year ago I wanted to learn Android and I started to make an application.
I know java/eclipse long, but not like other of you, as the language in which most have been deepened is C/C++.
But I always been a thing I've been missing, and it is the lack in the (language || IDE || Framework) , of not having a preprocessor as the M4 that C/C++ has.

To include similar directives as these.

- #DEFINE foo
- #IFDEF foo
- #IFNDEF foo
- #ENDIF

So that we avoid some code on the package. Or resources.

- Do you know any way/s to incorporate this feature in Android with Java or Eclipse or NetBeans or IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio or  plugin?.
- If you know several, in your opinion, What would be the best?.

Please, that this post does not turn into a war of which is the best solution, there's no accounting for taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With new gradle plugin you can use buildConfigField method of BuildType's or Flavor's DSL. 
It will generate a field in BuildConfig so you can use it later in code.

You can see example here: [BuildConfig not getting created correctly (Gradle Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706451/buildconfig-not-getting-created-correctly-gradle-android)

Answer (score -1):

You have a classic case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Java already gives you plenty of tools to reduce code duplication, use them. C-style #defines are not the solution.

Comment: So, what do you suggest? I'm writing an app which I want to generate different versions, but only write 1 code.
Please say me the name of this tools or a web that show me how to use them.

Comment: I guess that this is a start: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html . However, exatly what do you want to change per version?