# Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\bok\Desktop\ready Code Sours\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\sorie \BuildConfig.java (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)

solition please

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706451/buildconfig-not-getting-created-correctly-gradle-android

Comment: just clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error, try to

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Rebuild Project