# How to fix error "Unresolved reference: BuildConfig"?

Tags: android, gradle

After I added this piece of code into settings.gradle.kts the BuildConfig file is not being generated.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
       google()
       gradlePluginPortal()
       mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Banking"
include(":app")
```

How can I make it be generated again? But I need to keep the code inside settings.gradle.kts.

Edit:
I have already tried Invalidating caches and reloading the project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing the "Build Type contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled" error w/ buildConfigField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634321/fixing-the-build-type-contains-custom-buildconfig-fields-but-the-feature-is-di)

Comment: Did not fix the problem.

Comment: Try clicking on Gradle Sync.

Comment: Tried it now did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by migrating Gradle from 7.2.2 to 7.3.0. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 20):

When I faced this problem, adding the following code to the `build.gradle` of the `app` level helped me:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

Or you can add [the following the line](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildFeatures) in the `gradle.properties` file at the root project of your build:

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
```

Comment: Does not fix the problem.

Comment: Tried that one already. Did not work as well. But thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` after adding `buildConfig = true`?

Comment: Tried that now did not work.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284683/21590355) I saw that this method someone helped

Comment: Fixed it now by migrating Gradle from 7.2.2 to 7.3.0. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Highly underrated answer. I got this issue when switching to Gradle Kotlin from Groovy. Felt like this field was true by default in the Groovy world but not Kotlin.

Comment: Adding this is deprecated, any advice on how to fix?

Comment: @MrRobot, I checked it, and this decision is currently functioning correctly with the latest stable versions of AS and AGP: Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2, AGP 8.2.2. Have you tried to build your project with one of these options before calling BuildConfig?

Answer (score 0):

For those using expo, had the same issue. You need to go into your `android>app>build.gradle` and ensure that the namespace is correctly set to your application name:

```
android {
     ...
     namespace "com.yourapp.yourapp"
 }
```

(replace `com.yourapp.yourapp` with your actual app name) Mine was truncated to `"com.yourapp".`