# Gradle 8 - R file merging not working anymore?

Tags: android, gradle

In my project I have defined many strings inside a core module. After upgrading to gradle 8 I see that I need to reference R files exactly now.

E.g. if I define a string inside my core module and want to access it from my main module (the main module includes the core module of course) I see following behaviour:

**Before**

I could access strings (and all other resources) from the core module inside the main module via `com.my.package.main.R` and `com.my.package.core.R`

**After**

Now I can only access the strings from the exact module anymore so I need to use `com.my.package.core.R` inside my main module to access strings from the core module...

The same happens for attributes from `com.google.android.material.R` and `androidx.appcompat`...

---

Did I miss a migration step? Or should this really be like that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With AGP 8 the default behaviour did change:
See the option `android.nonTransitiveRClass` in
https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin

**android.nonTransitiveRClass**

New default: **true**   Old default: **false**

AGP 8.0 generates R classes for resources defined in the current module only.

Comment: thanks. I was looking for this documentation, now everything is clear

Comment: thanks a lot.  that fixes my project. Went to gradle.properties and add android.nonTransitiveRClass=false to merge R from other modules or libs.

Comment: I cannot say for certain if this is related, but after doing this change, I also had to `enableBuildConfig` as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75450056/2480714) for some reason. After doing that, I was able to create a signed build.